# CircuiTikZ: How to change the node options of labels and annotations?

Tags: tikz-pgf, circuitikz

How to access the node options of both the label and annotation to be able, for example, to set the maximum width, allow line break, or change the text align?

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V, l= some very \newline long label  ,a=some very \newline long annotation] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The usual Ti*k*Z methods work, of course. Just add the node options to the path.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw[nodes={align=center}] (0,0) to[V, l= some very \\ long label  ,a=some very \\ long annotation] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, you can distinguish between the labels, too.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V,nodes={align=center}, l= some very \\ long label  ,
        nodes={align=left,},a=some very \\ long annotation] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Or, for more complex operations, change *locally* the style of that element.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V,nodes={align=center}, l= some very \\ long label,
        bipole annotation style/.style={text=white,fill=blue,align=left},
        a=some very \\ long annotation] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 8):

Labels are actually implemented as separate nodes, so if you want to do something fancy, you might as well use separate nodes.  With `\centering`, `\\` works better than `\newline`.

Note that the actual width (5cm) is larger than the text, but since the text is centered you can't tell.  You might also look at the varwidth package.

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V, l={\parbox[b]{5cm}{\centering some very \\ long label}},
          a={\parbox[t]{5cm}{\centering some very \\ long annotation}}] ++(2,0);

        \draw (3,0) to[V, name=V1] ++(2,0);
        \node[above, text width=5cm, align=center] at (V1.n) {some very \\ long label};
        \node[below, text width=5cm, align=center] at (V1.s) {some very \\ long annotation};
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image: demo]

Answer (score 7):

Crude hack: put the label and annotation in a `tabular` environment.

```latex
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\newcommand\ml[3][c]{\begin{tabular}[#2]{@{}#1@{}}#3\end{tabular}}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
      \draw (0,0) to[V, l=\ml{b}{some very \\ long label}  ,a=\ml{t}{some very \\ long
      annotation}] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Literally any of the other answers (at the time writing this) is better than mine, whoever thinks this might be the way to go, please change your mind.

Answer (score 6):

For changing annotation and label styles, set `bipole annotation style` and `bipole label style`.

See MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=5mm]{standalone}
\usepackage[american]{circuitikz}
\ctikzset{
bipole annotation style/.style={red,text width=3cm,align=center},
bipole label style/.style={fill=blue!20, text width=3cm,align=center,anchor=south},
}
\begin{document}
    \begin{circuitikz}[thick]
        \draw (0,0) to[V, l= some very long label  ,a=some very long annotation] ++(2,0);
    \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Output:

[image]